# Имя поля объекта в качестве значения переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток друзья! Подскажите как в js можно назначить значение переменной именем поля объекта.

```
var typeLogin = 'phone' //значением может также быть email, login, id 
var myLogin = '+7 000 00 00 00' //значением может быть a@b.com, vasya, 1234

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'login.py',
    data: {
        'login': true,
         typeLogin: myLogin, // вот здесь именем поля должно быть значения переменной typeLogin а не ее имя 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data1 = { login: true };
data1[typeLogin] = myLogin;
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'login.py',
    data: data1
});
```

Comment: Изначально так и сделал, но хочется передать объект напрямую без создание доп. переменных

Comment: @XYZ - Мы не всегда получаем то, что хотим. Чем обусловлено Ваше желание не использовать дополнительную переменную?

Answer (score 2):

Если используешь ES6, то можно воспользоваться.

```
var typeLogin = 'phone' //значением может также быть email, login, id 
var myLogin = '+7 000 00 00 00' //значением может быть a@b.com, vasya, 1234

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'login.py',
    data: {
        'login': true,
         [typeLogin]: myLogin,  
    }
});
```

Правда поддержка браузерами может хромать. 
Юзабельно с Babel или в бэкенде с NodeJS.